# Face Recognition in Windows Logon

Tags: webview, face-recognition, winlogon

Good afternoon, I'm trying to make a personalized logo on Windows and I wanted to ask/know if it's possible to implement a facial recognition system in Windows logon (other than Windows Hello), because I want to be able to enter according to the data of the faces that will be in the database (Postgre).

I already tried the normal thing with the user name and password, I managed to create the DLL file and run Register.reg to change it in the registry editor but it ended up not being added.

If this method is impossible, can you tell me if it is possible to create a webview? Because I have a website in Django with Login with Facial recognition.
Thanks.

Here is where I got my code and made some changes:

[code](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/main/Samples/CredentialProvider)

Comment: Hello again :) Look at that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38975022/how-to-replace-the-logon-application-on-windows-10-with-a-custom-application